# want to create a new list from two variables, matching items sequentially

Tags: python, list, merge

From these two lists:

```
FCC = ["A3","A4","A5","A3"]

stNm = ["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "2nd"]
```

I want to produce a merged list like this:

```
list1 = [("A3, "1st"), ("A4", "2nd"),("A5","3rd"),("A3","2nd")]
```

I have started with this:

```
f = ''

n = ''

list1 = [ ]

for f in FCC:

    for n in stNm:

        list1.append((f,n))

print (list1)
```

but it gives me all possible combinations in list1. How can I get what I want? I think part of the issue may be with the loop but not sure how to resolve. I tried creating a dictionary but I need to retain duplicate keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the zip function.

zip (FCC, stNm)

Comment: thanks! now what I want to do is use a conditional statement if there are duplicate values in the tuples that correspond to different keys..

Comment: Do you mean you want to find pairs (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) where y1==y2 and x1!=x2? (for example, list1[1] and list1[3]?)

Comment: Easier to work with the original lists, maybe. For example: {item:stNm.count(item) for item in stNm} will give you a map of values to the number of times they appear. You can do this on the map of pairs, but it's a little more complex.

Comment: seems like maybe I can do something like: for x1,y1 in list1: for x2, y2 in list1: if x1 != x2 and y1 == y2: or is that not working how i think

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, you can get the list of duplicated items like so:

```
duplicated_items = [item for item in stNm if stNm.count(item)>1]
```

and then you can get the pairs that they belong to like so:

```
duplist = [pair for pair in zip(FCC, stNm) if pair[1] in dups]
```

Note:the duplicated_items list can be uniqued, as usual, by making it into a set(). This doesn't seem necessary for small lists, might be useful for huge ones.